# dart variable does not pass by reference

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

According to  [Dart Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts)   every data type is an object .
but when i pass an integer variable to a function it does not pass by reference as it should be if it is a object, i write this example for demenstration

```
void main() {
   int d =5;
   change(d);
   print(d);
   }
   void change(int x){
   x=0;
   }
```

the following code output : 5 .

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
void main() {
  int d = 5;
  d = change(d);
  print(d); // prints 0
}

int change(int x) {
  x = 0;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to return a value i want to change the variables because all variables are all objects that mean they should be passed by references

Comment: if they passed by references they should be able to change inside the function

Comment: if any thing passed by reference it should be able to change

Comment: This is not passing by reference at all!

Comment: My mistake, it was actually pass by value and not pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Dart. Support for struct value types, ref or val keywords. You can create global variable and then you can use inside the function. Good luck

Comment: i just knew  before asking this question it s not possible to do that in dart , but when the dart documentation said that every thing is object , they just confuse me

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not possible in Dart. Primitive types are passed by value, just like in languages such as Java. I was wondering about the same question just a few days ago. Unfortunately I was not able to find this specification in the documentation nor the language specification.

Comment: agree , i could only guess that primitive types which are objects are cloned before being passed as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Whether an integer is passed by value or by reference doesn't really matter. There are no integer methods that modify the object. Strings are definitely passed by reference in the sense that they do not get copied. But you can't modify them. And for any object, code like you've written will not modify the original. For example.

```
void main() {
   Map d = {};
   change(d);
   print(d);
 }
 void change(Map x){
   x={};
 }
```

Comment: i m sorry but i didn't understand  this sentence "There are no integer methods that modify the object"

Comment: How can you tell if an object is passed by reference or by value? The only way is by modifying internal state in one place and seeing if it is reflected in the other. A Dart int does not provide any methods or operators that modify state. Even incrementing an int is shorthand for re-assigning the variable with the value + 1. If you defined your own MyInt class with similar operations it would behave the same way.